# TikZ: "Cannot parse coordinate" with bend parabola

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a parabola with TikZ. Below is a minimal example, which gives me the error
`Cannot parse this coordinate` at the last `\draw` line. If I remove the `bend` part, I do not get this error.

What did I do wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) parabola bend (3, 4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `parabola bend` operation needs two coordinates at the end. See page 154 and 155 of [the PGF manual](http://ctan.triasinformatica.nl/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: That's it, thanks! If you submit it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `parabola bend` operation needs three coordinates in total, one before it to define the start point, and two after it to define the bend location and the end point.

Some other uses of the `parabola` operation are (taken from the [pgf manual](http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), page 155):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw               (0,0) rectangle                (1,1.5)
                        (0,0) parabola                 (1,1.5);
    \draw[xshift=1.5cm] (0,0) rectangle                (1,1.5)
                        (0,0) parabola[bend at end]    (1,1.5);
    \draw[xshift=3cm]   (0,0) rectangle                (1,1.5)
                        (0,0) parabola bend (.75,1.75) (1,1.5);
    \draw[xshift=4.5cm] (1,1.5) --
                        (0,0) parabola                 cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]